# $T-\lambda I$ is closed $\implies (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is closed

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, closed-map

Let X be a complex Banach Space ,$T:X\rightarrow X$ a linear operator, and $\lambda\in \rho(T)$(Resolvent set),If T is assumed to be closed ,then
I have to prove that

$T-\lambda I$ is closed $\implies (T-\lambda
 I)^{-1}$ is closed

I'm proving a result of "Spectral theory of Normed Spcaes" there is a gap in my proof which requires

> $T-\lambda I$ is closed $\implies (T-\lambda 
>  I)^{-1}$ is closed.

Please give any hint or suggestion to prove the above argument

Comment: @daw:$\rho(T) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lambda \mbox{ is a regular value of } T\}$.A Regular Value $\lambda$ of $T$ is a complex number such that (1)$R_{\lambda}(T)$ exists,(2)$R_{\lambda}(T)$ is bounded ,(3)$R_{\lambda}(T)$ is defined on a set which is dense in $X$

Comment: The graphs of $T-\lambda I$ and $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ are equal: $(x,y)\in \Gamma_{T-\lambda I}$ iff $(y,x)\in \Gamma_{(T-\lambda I)^{-1}}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc:Can we use closed graph theorem? or some characterization of Closed operator?

Comment: Closed graph theorem applies only when $D(T)=X.$ So we cannot use that. There is no need for any theorem, definitions suffice. Concerning my previous comment the injective function and its inverse have the same graph as a set: for example $y=x^2, x=y^{1/2}$ for $x>0$ have the same graph. The operator $T$ is closed if its graph is closed.